# onclick javascript in input tag that will get the id value in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, onclick

I have a code that is already working for a different function, I want to do the same in another way.

Here is the code that I want to somewhat imitate or being a guide:

```
<td>
    <a href="javascript:edit_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')">
        <img src="b_edit.png" align="center" />
    </a>
</td>
```

with a function:

```
function edt_id(id){
    if(confirm('Sure to edit ?')){
        window.location.href='newread.php?edit_id='+id;
    }
}
```

How can I do it in a input tag using onclick javascript?
Here is the code of the input tag that I want the javascript of getting the ID that is on the database:

```
<td>
    <input placeholder="<?php echo $row[3]; ?>" name="pre" type="number" value="<?php echo $pres; ?>" class="validate" onclick="?????????" min="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>" required>
</td>
```

I place question marks where I want the javascipt to be placed. Thanks!

Comment: replace `???`with `edit_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use onclick or onblur method to invoke edit_id()function.
Like

```
<td>
 <input placeholder="<?php echo $row[3]; ?>" name="pre" type="number" value="<?php echo $pres; ?>" class="validate" onclick="javascript:edit_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')" onblur="javascript:edit_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')" min="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>" required>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing i in "edt_id(id)" function

```
  function edit_id(id){
    if(confirm('Sure to edit ?')){
        window.location.href='newread.php?edit_id='+id;
    }
     }
```

and replace "question marks" with edit_id('')